# Retrieve data where row-cell and multiple column-cells match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of data with headlines and columns with id's and nodes (names). I need to retrieve row data from a Node typed (B10), where there is an "x" in row 1.

See image where I show the formulas I came up with. I tried to merge row-number formula (B11/B12) into filter formula (E12/E13) so the row number is dependent on the Node from B10 - but I didn't succeed !

(this is just testdata)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWipW.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(A2:H8, A1:H1="x"), "where Col1 = '"&B10&"'", 1)
```

[image]